# Change value of public variable in Java, used by multiple frames

Tags: java

I have two frames in NetBeans 9.0 as `frame1.java`, `frame2.java`and the main class as `main.java`.
If I declare a public variable in `frame1.java` as

```
public String stringName;
```

and a `function fn()` which gives the value of `stringName` in `frame1`as say `"abcd"`.

When I write this in `frame2`,

```
  frame1 fm = new frame1();
  String str = frame1.stringName;
  System.out.print(str);
```

I get the output as `null`. But what I require is `"abcd"`.

What am I doing wrong, and what should it be?

Thanks for help!

**Edit**:
I have linked `frame1` and `frame2` such that the GUI from `frame1` leads to `frame2`, and so does the value.

**Edit 2**

The process goes like this:

GUI of `frame1` is visible >> based on user's input, function `fn()` stores the value, say `"abcd"` in `stringName` >> a button click in `frame1` leads to `frame2`>> variable `str` gets the value from `stringName` >> `System.out.print(str)` outputs the value as `null` .

**CODE**

- frame1:

  ```
  public class frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  public String stringName;
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
  stringName = jTextField1.getText(); // gets a not null value
  }
  }}
  ```
- frame2:

  ```
  public class frame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  frame1 fm = new frame1();
  String str = frame1.stringName;
  System.out.print(str); //outputs a null value
  }
  ```

Comment: you'll need to show more code. but it looks like between the instantiation of your first frame, and getting the value of stringName, you don't set it

Comment: "But what I require is "abcd"." Where do you set it to `"abcd"`?

Comment: Where do you call `fn()`? In the constructor of `frame1`? I can't see the call in the lines of code you provided...

Comment: abcd is the value I get from running the function fn() from frame1

Comment: You are instantiating frame1 in frame2, so frame1.stringName is null. Pass a reference of frame1 to frame2 and use it without instantiation.

Comment: @Natasha yes, but you don't call the fn() method. that's the point

Comment: @Natasha why don't you create the getter and setter in your class and you can get the data using get method or else show the code of `frame1`

Comment: call `fm.fn()` in frame 2 before printing str

Comment: This is how my code of frame 1 looks like : [https://repl.it/repls/JumboPlayfulCharacters](https://repl.it/repls/JumboPlayfulCharacters) and frame2 :[https://repl.it/repls/EmotionalVioletDictionary](https://repl.it/repls/EmotionalVioletDictionary)

Comment: edit the question and post your code there.

Answer (score 0):

The point ist that you are crating a new Instance (frame1, fm) in your class frame2. So the value from the string in this new Instance is null. You need a reference to your old Instance which you maybe have initialised in your main method?

Something like that:

```
String str = myOldInstance.stringName;
```

But you should create getter an setter and make your var private.
But to help you exactly we need more Code.

Comment: I don't quite know about the getter and setter methods, but can you please tell about how to initialize the old instance, in frame2?

Comment: Yeah I can, but can you send me the Code of your Main class?

Comment: @Natasha if you don't know how to use getters and setters, you don't know the basics. start with the basics and make sure you understand that first. don't go for UI development before you know what you are doing

Comment: Actually I don't have anything in main class, but just referred to the ```frame1``` in ```frame2``` 's code

Comment: @Natasha the main class is the class with the entry point of your application. it isn't called Main.java. It's the class in which you have a public static void main(String[] args) method

Comment: I see you have 2 main classes? How should that work? Which class runs really?

Comment: @Natasha you may get this to work, but without basic java knowledge every implementation will be like this one, that is consulting several other developers via an internet forum and asking for help. Instead, gain knowledge about object orientation in Java, like Stultuske suggested.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the best is Listener pattern. 
Create interface of listener, which will inform about change text. In class - target of this information - create instance of this listener and return that. In class - source of information - set listener and put on field.

When you want inform of change text, you fire method of listener, and on seconde frame will execute implementation of method.

Below example - I fire on button click.
Any way, field should be private, and add getter and setter. Public fields are bad.

**Main class**

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame1 f1=new Frame1();
    Frame2 f2=new Frame2();

    TextListener textListener = f2.getListener();
    f1.setListener(textListener);
}
```

}

**Listener**

```
public interface TextListener {

public void onTextPropagate(String text);
```

}

**Frame classes**

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame{

private TextListener listener;
JButton button;

public Frame1() {
    super("Frame1");
    setBounds(200, 200, 400, 600);
    button=new JButton("Action");
    button.setBounds(100, 200, 200, 100);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(listener!=null) {
                String text = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                System.out.println("On Frame1:\t"+text);
                listener.onTextPropagate(text);
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(button);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void setListener(TextListener listener) {
    this.listener=listener;
}
```

}

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame{

public Frame2() {
    super("Frame2");
    setBounds(100, 100, 200, 400);
    setVisible(true);
}

public TextListener getListener() {
    return new TextListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTextPropagate(String text) {
            reactOnChangeText(text);
        }
    };
}

private void reactOnChangeText(String text) {
    System.out.println("On Frame2:\t"+text);
}
```

}

Comment: the OP does not know how to use getters, but you would recommend to implement a Listener?

Comment: Look at main method in App class - first class. There are example how use getter and put listener to other frame.  Implementation of listener is in 'getListener()' method. From listener you can call other method in class.

Comment: Listener you create in place, where you need information about changes. Listener you 'send' to place where changes happen. Call listener method in sytuation, when you want to inform about changes

Comment: I know what a Listener does. My point is, the OP does not (yet) understand the concept of getStringName() { return stringName; }
She doesn't have enough knowledge of the basics of Java to do something like this half decent